# different behavior of unicodedata.normalize method

Tags: python, unicode-normalization

The following code is taken from [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/518232/2809427) SO Post.

```
def unicodeToAscii(s):
    return ''.join(
        c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
        if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'
        and c in all_letters
    )
```

When i run this

```
print(unicodeToAscii('Ślusàrski'))
```

i get the following output

```
Slusarski
```

But, when i just run `unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Ślusàrski')` i get the same old string `Ślusàrski` as output.

The code in the function is just doing the same and ignoring all the characters that are not if category `Mn` and if it is in in `all_letters`. why is that i am not getting the same with normalize method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Ślusàrski')` may *look* the same as the input string, but it's not.  If we use `ascii()` to force all non-ASCII characters to be shown with `\uXXXX` escapes, we get:

```
>>> print(ascii(unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Ślusàrski')))
'S\u0301lusa\u0300rski'
```

Here we see the effects of NFD: Each accented character is decomposed into a nonaccented character plus an accent character (with category Mn).  This is why the rest of your first code snippet produces `Slusarski`: it's not operating on `Ś`, it's operating on `S`+`´`.

Comment: thanks , i just ran `print([i for i in unicodedata.normalize('NFD','Ślusàrski')])` and got `['S', '́', 'l', 'u', 's', 'a', '̀', 'r', 's', 'k', 'i']` as  output. you are right. But, why did python combine these first two characters and print it as a single character?

Comment: @InAFlash: Because that's how modifier characters work; their whole deal is that they're combined with the previous character when printing.

Comment: oh, thank you very much. so, i just need to make it a list and remove those characters. Thanks